# How can I close a Stellar Account?

Tags: accounts, fees

According to the [Minimum Account Balance](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html#minimum-account-balance) information, the account has to have

```
(2 + # of entries) * 0.5) XLM
```

deposited to support transactions.

Let's say there is an account with 0 trust lines and 1 data entry. It means that the account has to have min 1.5 xlm.

Is it possible to close that account and withdraw the deposit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Stellar Expert's "account demolisher":
https://stellar.expert/demolisher/public

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 7):

The [account merge operation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#account-merge) does that.

I don't know any wallet that supports it, but an easy way to do it without programming is [stellar laboratory](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/)

- If there are any other assets move them with regular payments first.
- Go to [stellar laboratory transaction builder](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#txbuilder?network=public)
- Enter the account you want to have removed as "Source account"
- Click on "Fetch sequence number..."
- Scroll to the bottom, select "Account Merge" as operation type
- Enter the account you want the remaining XLM transfered to as "Destination"
- Click on "Sign in transaction signer"
- Enter your private key at "Add Signer" (or connect Ledger and "Sign with BIP")
- "Submit to Post Transaction endpoint"
- "Submit"

Comment: It seams that this doesn't work. When an account has a data, I'm getting the following error: `accountMergeResult: [accountMergeHasSubEntry]`. TX hash: bf6acd8bf0e9464ef1b5ca35fb7aafd5e9b34991c73c6348f50bd703d592eed9 (testnet)

Comment: This error code is also documented in the "merge account" spec: ACCOUNT_MERGE_HAS_SUB_ENTRIES. It  seams that it's not possible to merge account if it has trust lines offers and data (the last part is not documented).